# How to populate look up tables in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Hi i am working on look up tables first time and we have some distinct values in look up tables which are coming from excel sheets. So i have two databases say A and B. there are around 22 look up tables and 5 certified tables in database A. and one import table and few work table in database B. i am just wondering how i am going to load Look up tables. do i have to write stored procs for each look up table and use in SSIS package. i just have to get distinct values from the Excel sheet for respective look up tables. i am using SQL Server 2005. Thanks for reading this.

Comment: certified tables have all the history of the data from work tables. each time package would run it would load work table then certified table from work table and truncate work table.

Answer (score 0):

1) Save the excel sheet as csv (use "Save As" from file menu)

2) Set "IGNORE_DUP_KEY"  option on the destination table, this will skip duplicate values in CSV files(excel sheet)

3) construct a  BULK INSERT command and provide the csv file and the destination table.

Alternative to 2)  You may also set MAXERRORS in the BULK INSERT command to a value higher than the number of lines in csv file, this options just ignores any errors(there fore all the duplicate key errors will not cause the INSERT to fail)